# Signal and slot example not working

Tags: c++, qt

While trying to familiarize myself to the signal slot concept. I came up with the following code

```
class Person: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT 
public:
    void SignalEmitter(QString Words); //This emits the signal
    Person(QObject *parent = 0);
signals:
    void Call(QString Words); //This is the signal
};

class Animal: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT 
public:
    Animal(QObject *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void Respond(QString Words); //This is the slot
};

class SomeClass: public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT 
        public:
        SomeClass(QObject *parent = 0);
};
```

Now the objective is simple - The person sends a signal and the animal receives it in a slot
Here is my implementation

```
void Person::SignalEmitter(QString Words)
{
    //Emit the signal
    emit Call("Signal emitted");
}

void Animal::Respond(QString Words)
{
    qDebug() <<"Responding " << Words;
    std::string d= "Breakpoint should be here";
}
```

//This is the code

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{
    Person *p = new Person();
    Animal *a = new Animal();
    connect(p,SIGNAL(SignalEmitter(QString)) ,a,SLOT(Respond(QString)));
    p->SignalEmitter("Lassie");
    std::string d = "dd";
}
```

Unfortunately the breakpoint never hits `Animal::Respond(QString Words)` any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: also make sure this is converted into a `QString` :`"Signal emitted"`. Qt is very sensitive to types in slots signals

Comment: Wonder why I got a downvote ? Looks like a total legit question

Comment: I gave you an upvote back. Seems like a fine enough question, minimal code posted that allowed me to easily scan through it for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the SIGNAL in the following

```
connect(p,SIGNAL(SignalEmitter(QString)) ,a,SLOT(Respond(QString)));
```

should be

```
SIGNAL(Call(QString))
```

You connect a signal to a slot, i.e. Call to Respond

Comment: connect(p, SIGNAL(Call(QString)), a, SLOT(Respond(QString)));  // to be precise

Comment: Yeah, I just meant replace SignalEmitter(QString) by Call(QString), let me edit just the Call part to remove the 'Words' part and make clear it's the SIGNAL